# Find $\det A$ and $\operatorname{Tr} A$ if $\det(A-\sqrt[n]{3}I_n)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ and I have to find $\det A$ and $\operatorname{Tr} A$ if $\det(A+\sqrt[n]{3}I_n)=0$. I observed that $\sqrt[n]{3}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$,but I don't know how to continue.
EDIT : My bad,the matrix has rational entries.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to answer if we only know that $a \in M_n(\Bbb C)$.  Do we have some other information?  Does $A$ have integer or rational entries?

Comment: Yes,I made an edit,sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\det (A+\lambda I_n)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ in $\lambda$. Note that if $n$-th root of $3$ is a root of a degree $n$-polynomial, the polynomial must be a multiple of $\lambda^n-3$, hence $\det$ and Tr must be $(-1)^n\cdot -3$ and $0$ respectively (by using the fact that Tr is the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ in the characteristic polynomial and $\det$ is the constant term times $(-1)^n$ in the characteristic polynomial).

Comment: Why must the polynomial be a multiple of $\lambda ^n -3$?

Comment: That is because the minimal polynomial of $n$-th root of $3$ is $x^n-3$, i.e. there is no polynomial that admits $n$-th root of $3$ as a root and has degree less than $n$.

Comment: @Arthur you are most definitely right, I guess I just automatically made some assumptions. However in this case there are matrices that satisfy the condition and have different trace and determinant which makes me believe that OP may have meant rational entries.

Comment: @Levent one more question : if the characteristic polynomial is a multiple of $\lambda^n -3$,why do we still get that $\det$ and $Tr$ must be $(-1)^n\cdot -3$ and $0$?Shouldn't they be a multiple of $(-1)^n\cdot -3$ and $0$?

Comment: Well, characteristic polynomial of a matrix is necessarily a monic polynomial, i.e. its leading coefficient is always $1$, hence the characteristic polynomial must be $\lambda^n-3$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,now I understand !

Comment: You are welcome. If you have troubles with any of the facts I pull out of the hat, I can edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: Why is it not possible for the root to be $\lambda - 3^{1/n}$?